# Vsphere Virtual Machines generating same IP while provisioning through terraform count metadata

Tags: terraform, vsphere, terraform-provider-vsphere

I want to provision multiple virtual machines in Vsphere through terraform. I am using **count** metadata for provisioning parallel VM, Sometimes multiple VMs get the same IP addresses. I tried multiple ways to handle it, but no luck. Please assist me to understand how to handle this scenario. I don't want to use static IPs. I am using DHCP.

When I create multiple VMs sequentially, VMs get the proper **IP address**, but when I tried to create using **count meta-data** (trying to provision multiple VMs parallel) that time it failed.

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
   count = "3"
   name = "${var.vm_name}-${count.index+1}"
   resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
   datastore_id     = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
   folder = "VirtualMachines"
   guest_id = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id
   scsi_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type

   wait_for_guest_net_timeout = 0
   
   num_cpus             = var.cpu
   num_cores_per_socket = var.cores-per-socket
   memory               = var.ram

   network_interface {
    network_id   = data.vsphere_network.network.id
    adapter_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]
   }

   
   disk {
    label            = "${var.vm_name}-${count.index+1}-disk"
    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned
   # eagerly_scrub    = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.eagerly_scrub
    size             = var.disksize == "" ? data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size : var.disksize
   }

   clone {
      template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id 
   }
   wait_for_guest_ip_timeout = 3
}
```

Comment: What is `data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]`?

Comment: `+ network_interface {
          + adapter_type          = "vmxnet3"
          + bandwidth_limit       = -1
          + bandwidth_reservation = 0
          + bandwidth_share_count = (known after apply)
          + bandwidth_share_level = "normal"
          + device_address        = (known after apply)
          + key                   = (known after apply)
          + mac_address           = (known after apply)
          + network_id            = "network-22"
        }

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, I got vmxnet3 as adapter_type

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says the following [1] (search for DHCP in that section):

> To use DHCP, declare an empty network_interface block for each interface.

So in your case, that would mean changing the `network_interface` block to:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
   ...

   network_interface {}
   ...
}
```

Also, you are using a combination of `wait_for_guest_net_timeout` and `wait_for_guest_ip_timeout`. The documentation says that for the newer versions of VMware Tools you need only the former. Be careful about setting that timeout as if set to less than 1 the waiter is disabled [2].

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#virtual-machine-customizations

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#wait_for_guest_net_timeout